# Error: Wallet has error: Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.0.17)

Tags: ethers.js, besu

After enabling JWT token authentication on besu network, a [connectionInfo](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/web/#ConnectionInfo) with JWT token in `headers` is used to make connection to the network, instead of url.

```
import { ContractFactory, ethers } from "ethers";
let connectionInfo = {  //<<==connectionInfo may have problem. Used to use url and worked fine.
   url: GLOBAL.PROVIDER_URL, //<<=="http://my-ip:80"
   headers: {
     "Bearer": tokenBesu //<<==tokenBesu is validated on jwt.io and OKed with cUrl command querying the network
},

};
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(connectionInfo); //<<==used to be url
wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKeyBesu, provider); //<<== this line throws error
```

However querying network with `cUrl` (provided by Besu doc) in command line returns `true`.

```
$ curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer tokenBesu' -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_listening","params":[],"id":1}' http://my-ip:80
{
  "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
  "id" : 1,
  "result" : true
}
```

The network is running fine. What causes the no detection of network here?

Comment: Did you try with `Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tokenBesu` in headers?